# Double integral application

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, logarithms

I need to determine $$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{-\sqrt{x}}^{\sqrt{x}}\frac{1}{1-y}dydx$$

I integrate in terms of the y component and obtained: $$\int_{0}^{1}\ln(\frac{1+\sqrt{x}}{1-\sqrt{x}})dx$$

Can someone help me with the integral in terms of the x component ?

Thank you

Comment: Presumably you really want to evaluate the double integral the hard way, instead of integrating first with respect to $x$.

Comment: Yeah I just realized that it's easier the other way

Answer (score 9):

Note that $$\ln \left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{x}}{1-\sqrt{x}}\right) = \ln(1+\sqrt{x}) - \ln(1-\sqrt{x})$$
$$\underbrace{\int \ln(1\pm\sqrt{x})dx = \int \ln(1 \pm t)2tdt}_{x = t^2} = \dfrac12 \left(2(t^2-1)\log(1\pm t)-t(t\mp 2)\right) + \text{constant}$$

Another way would be to integrate over $x$ first.
We have
$$\int_0^1 \int_{-\sqrt{x}}^{\sqrt{x}} \dfrac{dy}{1-y} dx = \int_{y=-1}^1 \int_{x=y^2}^1 \dfrac{dx}{1-y}dy = \int_{y=-1}^1 \dfrac{1-y^2}{1-y} dy = \int_{y=-1}^1 (1+y) dy = 2$$

---

**EDIT**
Here is a figure explaining the order of integration and the corresponding limits. The area you are integrating over is the parabola given by $x=y^2$ and the boundary on the right hand side $x=1$.

The way you are integrating you integrate along the yellow strip first and move the yellow strip from $x=0$ to $x=1$. Instead, integrate along the red strip and move the red strip from $y=-1$ to $y=1$.

[image]

Comment: Nice answer, +1. Could you tell me what software you used to produce this picture?

Comment: @julien This was made using Grapher on Max OS X 10.7.

Comment: Thanks! I've had that on my iMac for three years without knowing it...

Comment: @julien It is actually a pretty powerful software. Enjoy playing around with it!

Comment: @julien Could you explain how do we change the order of the integrals ? Like instead of integrating with respect to x, how do we change the limits of the integrals in order to integrate with respect to y.

Thank you

Comment: @user43418 Note this is not my answer. This is [Fubini's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini's_theorem), which applies when the function is intergrable.

Comment: @julien I know that it's Fubini's theorem but when doing worked examples, how do we actually proceed in order to change the limits? Could you please explain

Comment: @user43418 As it is given in your question, the domain of integration is parametrized as follows: $D=\{(x,y)\; 0\leq x\leq 1,\;-\sqrt{x}\leq y\leq \sqrt{x}\}$. That is the union of the yellow segments in the picture above. Now You can parametrize as the union of the red segments. This yields $D=\{(x,y)\;;\; y^2\leq x\leq 1,\;0\leq y\leq 1\}$. In the first case, $x$ is the parameter, so you integrate with respect to $x$ first. In the second case, $y$ is the parameter, so integrate with respect to $y$ first.

Comment: @julien So if I have $1 \leq x \leq 4$ and $\sqrt{x} \leq y \leq 2$ then we have: $1\leq x \leq y^2$ and $1 \leq y \leq 2$ ?

Comment: @user43418 Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 3):

When confronted with a double integral, you should always consider the possibility of switching the order of integration. This problem becomes much easier if you do so. There are many (often, admittedly, artificial) problems that are undoable in one order and easy in the other.